# Python Dataframe: How to check specific columns for elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, exists

I want to check whether all elements from a certain column contain the number 0?

I have a dataset that I read with `df=pd.read_table('ad-data')`
From this I felt a data frame with elements

```
[0] [1.] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] ....1559

[1.]  3   2   3   0   0   0   0

[2]  2   3   2   0   0   0   0

[3]  3   2   2   0   0   0   0

[4]  6   7   3   0   0   0   0

[5]  3   2   1   0   0   0   0

...
3220
```

I would like to check whether the data set from column 4 to 1559 contains only 0 or also other values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for equality with 0 element-wise and use `all` for rows:

```
df['all_zeros'] = (df.iloc[:, 4:1560] == 0).all(axis=1)
```

Small example to demonstrate it (based on columns 1 to 3 here):

```
N = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, 0.4, size=(N, N)))
df['all_zeros'] = (df.iloc[:, 1:4] == 0).all(axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  all_zeros
0  0  1  1  0  0      False
1  0  0  1  1  1      False
2  0  1  1  0  0      False
3  0  0  0  0  0       True
4  1  0  0  0  0       True
```

**Update:** Filtering non-zero values:

```
df[~df['all_zeros']]
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  all_zeros
0  0  1  1  0  0      False
1  0  0  1  1  1      False
2  0  1  1  0  0      False
```

**Update 2:** To show only non-zero values:

```
pd.melt(
    df_filtered.iloc[:, 1:4].reset_index(),
    id_vars='index', var_name='column'
).query('value != 0').sort_values('index')
```

Output:

```
   index column  value
0      0      1      1
3      0      2      1
4      1      2      1
7      1      3      1
2      2      1      1
5      2      2      1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it. How i can print that information

Comment: i got the Error: cannot do slice indexing on Index with these indexers [4] of type int

Comment: Your column names are probably strings then. If they start from 0 and are in ascending order, you can try the same replacing `.loc` with `.iloc`, which would look up columns not based on their name, but by their index instead. I've updated the answer to use `.iloc`

Comment: Wow thank you, Wow thank you, I have now received false values. Is it now possible to output the non-zero?

Comment: You mean to filter only those with at least one non-zero value, right? Something like `df_filtered = df[~df['all_zeros']]`

Comment: Yes, exactly, I would like to see what values are hidden underneath.

Comment: OK, please see the update. Is this what you were after?

Comment: My dataset is very large so I cannot illustrate this

Comment: Not sure which way you want to see it then, but maybe one option is to show row-column-value for each non-zero value there. I've added `update 2` with an example

Comment: 9837 rows × 3 columns i am getting that much rows with your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Check']=df.loc[:,4:].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: @DimaGraf Yes, it stands from column 4 to end.

Answer (score 0):

> here is the way to check if all of values are zero or not: it's simple
> and **doesn't need advanced functions** as above answers. only basic
> functions like filtering and if loops and variable assigning.
>
> first is the way to check if one column has only zeros or not and
> second is how to find if all the columns have zeros or not. and it
> prints and answer statement.

**the method to check if one column has only zero values or not:**

first make a series:

```
 has_zero = df[4] == 0
 # has_zero is a series which contains bool values for each row eg. True, False.
 # if there is a zero in a row it result will be "row_number : True"
```

next:

```
rows_which_have_zero = df[has_zero]
# stores the rows which have zero as a data frame
```

next:

```
if len[rows_which_have_zero] == total_number_rows:
    print("contains only zeros")
else: 
    print("contains other numbers than zero")
# substitute total_number_rows for 3220
```

the above method only checks if rows_which_have_zero is equal to amount of the rows in the column.

**the method to see if all of the columns have only zero or not:**

it uses the above function and puts it into a if loop.

```
no_of_columns = 1559
value_1 = 1

if value_1 <= 1559
     has_zero = df[value_1] == 0
     rows_which_have_zero = df[has_zero]
     value_1 += 1
     if len[rows_which_have_zero] == 1559 
         no_of_rows_with_only_zero += 1
     else:
         return
```

to check if all rows have zero only or not:

```
   #since it doesn't matter if first 3 columns have zero or not:
   no_of_rows_with_only_zero = no_of_rows_with_only_zero - 3
   if no_of_rows_with_only_zero == 1559:
       print("there are only zero values")
   else:
       print("there are numbers which are not zero")
```

above checks if no_of_rows_with_only_zero is equal to the amount of rows (which is 1559 minus 3 because only rows 4 - 1559 need to be checked)

update:

```
  # convert the value_1 to str if the column title is a str instead of int 
  # when updating value_1 by adding: convert it back to int and then back to str
```

Comment: note: this answer only uses simple functions and its possible to shorten this code by uses advanced functions such as above answers

Comment: Also note: there might be an error when the code checks the first column because the title of that column is [1.] with a dot at the end. so to avoid the error - rename the column title to [1] or update the above code so it doesn't check the first column